# Database layout/design inefficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

The image shows my proposed layout for part of a database. My concern is with the price bands and the way these attach to [shows] and [bookings]. There needs to be a list of price bands (as in titles) but the same band can have multiple values depending on which show it is attached to (a standard ticket for Friday could be £10 where as a standard ticket on Saturday could be £11).

It just seems to me with this approach them will be a lot of almost identical data - lots of entries for £5 tickets in [showpriceband] with the only difference being the showid.

Is there a better approach to this?

[image: proposed database layout]

Comment: Is there 1 to 1 relationship between Show and ShowPriceBand? In other words, will there be one show per day?

Comment: There can be any number of shows in one day, 1 to many from show to showpriceband

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your approach is correct. You have

- different ticket types
- different shows

And their relation is n:n. The correct solution for resolving a n:n relation is a separate table (in your case ShowPriceBand) to enlist all the combinations.

Answer (score 2):

As the relationship between `Show` and `PriceBand` is many-to-many, it is a standard approach to define an intermediary table to define this relationship. In your case, apart from the linking columns (foreign keys to `Show` and `PriceBand`) you defined additional properties of the link.

This is a valid approach and there is no need to reduce possible duplication of those additional fields.

Comment: So how are you going to do that with ShowDateTime in Shows table? Same for bookings? You book one specific show, I guess?

Comment: A show can have multiple pricebands and multiple bookings, a booking and priceband may only have one show.

Comment: So what about ShowDateTime in Shows table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand. So in what way can one show have multiple price bands?

Comment: Example: A Show (Performance) is on at 7pm this Friday, it has the price bands 'Standard Price', 'Student Price' and 'Half Price'. There can be multiple 'Bookings' for this show with any combination of the available price bands.

Comment: Ok, got it! My answer is not correct then, I'll remove it. Or better correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this issue:

> It just seems to me with this approach them will be a lot of almost
>   identical data - lots of entries for £5 tickets in [showpriceband]
>   with the only difference being the showid.

You can avoid this duplication with adding a join table between show and showpriceband tables. I don't think it would be really natural, but it depends on your data. (and probably you should rename showpriceband also...)

Or maybe you can consider moving the fields from showpriceband to priceband. (value, ongeneralsale) sausing a bit more redundancy there, but making the showpriceband table more connecting table like.